# firewalld on EC2 Amazon Linux 2 - no icmptypes found

Tags: amazon-ec2, firewalld, amazon-linux-2

On freshly-booted Amazon EC2 instance (Amazon Linux 2), the firewalld could not be started. Executing `systemctl start firewalld` gives several warnings and errors (details below), boiling down to: `no icmptypes found` and `no such file or directory: '/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_helper'`.

Any advices are highly appreciated.

```
# uname -r
4.14.173-137.229.amzn2.x86_64

# cat /etc/os-release

NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"


# systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2020-04-10 11:11:29 UTC; 17min ago
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
  Process: 2736 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid $FIREWALLD_ARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2736 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

... firewalld[2736]: WARNING: unknown-header-type: INVALID_ICMPTYPE: No supported ICMP type., ignoring for run-time.
... firewalld[2736]: WARNING: ICMP type 'unknown-option' is not supported by the kernel for ipv6.
... firewalld[2736]: WARNING: unknown-option: INVALID_ICMPTYPE: No supported ICMP type., ignoring for run-time.
... firewalld[2736]: ERROR: No icmptypes found.
... firewalld[2736]: ERROR: Failed to read file "/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_helper": [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_helper'
... firewalld[2736]: WARNING: Failed to get and parse nf_conntrack_helper setting
... firewalld[2736]: WARNING: iptables not usable, disabling IPv4 firewall.
... firewalld[2736]: WARNING: ip6tables not usable, disabling IPv6 firewall.
... firewalld[2736]: FATAL ERROR: No IPv4 and IPv6 firewall.
... firewalld[2736]: ERROR: Raising SystemExit in run_server
```

UPDATE: 
It seems that my system doesn't have `nf_conntrack`:

```
# lsmod | grep nf_conntrack
(empty output)
```

Comment: Lots of stuff is broken in Amazon Linux 2, or breaks unexpectedly and (only sometimes) gets fixed later. There's very little quality control with this distro. After updating Amazon Linux 2 I can start firewalld successfully. But it might break again next week. Consider using something more reliable.

Answer (score -1):

Check if selinux is enforcing. If that is the case make it permissive , restart firewalld and then bring back selinux to enforcing.